# Angular 2 same class instance between components

Tags: angular, typescript

So, im quite new with angular 2, so far so good.
The problem that im having (may be because so use to angular 1) is that i need the class user to be global and use it between diferent components.

in my case i got a `User` class and im login the user in one component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
  providers: [User]
})
export class loginComponent {
  submitted = false;
  username  : string;
  password  : string;
  constructor(public user : User){}
  onSubmit(event) { //form event
    event.preventDefault();
    this.user.login(this.username,this.password, () =>{this.router.navigateByUrl('dashboard')}
```

So the method login in user is setting the internal variables of user, like name, last name, etc.
in the router i have a diferent component asigned to the route dashboard.
so when i import `User` i got a new instance of the class. how can i mantain the data in the class?

Comment: Don't declare the User in the component's providers. Declare it in the root NgModule's providers.

Comment: ...i dont have, a ngModule, im bootstraping a mainComponent...like the documentation says...i injected the providers on that component and worked, i guess is like the old scope thing with angular 1

Comment: That must be old documentation you're looking at then. Read https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html. But you'll have the same effect if you declare it in the providers of the root component.

Answer (score 2):

First I would suggest use 'UserService' rather `User`.

You are looking for [Application-wide dependencies](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#app-wide-dependencies), That needs to be provided at a Higher Level, preferably in your `AppComponent` or `AppModule`.

In a nutshell in your application wherever you add a service in `providers` array, a new instance will be used in that component and any child components.

Hence you are getting new instance of the service, when you define provider in `AppComponent` and not in `loginComponent`, the same instance can be injected there.

Hope this helps!!